# How to match a number in one file to a name in another file?

Tags: awk, grep, uniq

*Okay, I hope this is the right place to ask.  I have 2 files.*

The first file has 4 fields: class CRN #, Instructor ID #, Class Section #, Number of Students.

Example:

```
0002  T00005  006  15
0004  T00004  012  26
.
.
etc
```

The second file has 6 fields (as best as I can tell):  Instructor ID #, First Name, Last Name, Building, Area Code, Phone Number.

(not sure if first/last name is 1 or two fields...)

Example:

```
T00001  Larry Lastname  Corley  555  555-5555
T00002  Ron  Lastname  Coreley  555  111-1111
.
.
etc
```

The question I'm supposed to answer is: how many sections did each instructor teach in a given semester?  The solution needs to be in the form of:

```
# of sections | Instructor ID # | FirstName | LastName
```

(I just use the '|' for demonstration - The solution actually just uses spaces)

So far, I have done this:

```
$ cat sections/sem092 | sort -k 2 | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq -c
```

(`sem092` is the first file I mentioned)

And the output was *so* close to what I need.  From the above code I got:

```
Num. of Sections Taught |  Instructor ID #
```

Somehow, through pipes, I have to match the ID # with the names in the other file.  I have a very strong feeling I'm going to need to use `grep`.  I'm not looking for anyone to "hold my hand".  I find this extremely interesting, but I think I've missed something along the way and need a nudge or two.

Comment: I added the extra stuff if you haven't seen it.  But, I also wanted add that this problem is one of the harder(ish) ones and very representative of the rest of them - so, if I can get this one down, it will go a long way if not be enough to get me through the rest.  I worked on this single problem for probably 3-4 hours yesterday (and there are 20 altogether).  I thought I was going to have a heart attack or stroke or something - literally.  I feel much more sedated and able to finish it today.

Comment: You are more likely to get good answers if you post a **complete, minimal** example - your example as it stands only has a single instance of each instructor ID, and neither of the IDs in the first file actually appears in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save output of your command:

```
 cat sections/sem092 | sort -k 2 | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq -c > firstPart.txt
```

Save this line in file `searchInstructorName.sh`:

```
 cat $1 | while read line; do 
    instructorID=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` 
    name=`grep $instructorID instructorList | awk '{print $2 " " $4}'`
    echo "$line $name" 
 done
```

This script assume that `firtsPart.txt` line look like:

```
5 T00005
```

and that `instructorList` is the name of file with 6 field.

Finally try:

```
bash searchInstructorName.sh firstPart.txt
```

it should works.

---

This is the version with a single script:

```
 cat $1 | sort -k 2 | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq -c | while read line; do 
    instructorID=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` 
    name=`grep $instructorID $2 | awk '{print $2 " " $4}'`
    echo "$line $name" 
 done
```

Save these lines in `searchInstructorInfo.sh` and run:

```
 bash searchInstructorInfo.sh sections/sem092 instructorList
```

Comment: Wow.  That is VERY VERY close (I tried to upvote but I don't have enough..something).  Everything for this assignment is in the same file.  The professor wrote a script to echo the questions, then we just add the code underneath his echoes.  SO, I need a way to do pretty much exactly what you showed but only running his single ".sh" file (without running the separate file with it).  Is there some way of bringing those two together within his single sh file?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your detailed responses Letizia.  I used bits and pieces of your code and some of your code, in turn, gave me more ideas.  Just to not leave this post hanging:  my final (gruesome) code ended up like this:

```
 cat sections/sem092 | sort -k 2 | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq -c > no3 
 paste instructors | awk '{ print $2 " " $3 }' > no3n   
   #guess I could have just used cat above
 paste no3 no3n
```

I know this code is mortifying - I showed my professor today and he was like:  "Hmm...Let me see.  What have you done here?"   lol.  But after he looked at it, he said it was fine.  He always says: "There's more than one way to skin the proverbial cat".

Thanks for the help all - namely Letizia.